# How to I make use of react-toolbox icons

Tags: reactjs, react-toolbox

I'm using `react-toolbox` for my project.

I have tried some feature that it has, i.e icon button. and now i need a button with `arrow-u`p icon. i dont know whether it is provided by react-toolbox or not.

`<Button icon='arrow-up' floating />`

The code above doesnt show any icon on the button

How do I use the `arrow-up` icon? Any help is appreciated

Comment: This is a trivial question about documentation. Please use a web search engine to find and answer. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Toolbox is a set of React components that implement `Google's Material Design specification`.

According to the **[Github page](https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox#roboto-font-and-material-design-icons)**

> **Roboto Font and Material Design Icons**
>
> React Toolbox assumes that you are importing Roboto Font and Material
>   Design Icons.
>
> In order to import the fonts for you, we'd need to include them in the
>   CSS which is considered a bad practice. If you are not including them
>   in your app, go to the linked sites and follow the instructions.

Since it uses material-icon, you can get all the icons list from **[material icons](https://material.io/icons/)**

For the arrow up icon you would use

```
 <Button icon='keyboard-arrow-up' floating />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. for temporary solution, i have download svg icon from material-icon and include them on my project.

but, i thought there are some icon that had been downloaded when i installed react toolbox, so i dont have to download icon from material-icon again. cmiiw.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with icons not showing, you probably forgot to add to the .html file the following link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

Check web material.io installation guide:
https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/